# launch application by name in android phone

Tags: applications

How can I launch some android application by name on android device? Like in Linux, I pressed alt+f2 and typed name of application. May be it is some alternate launcher.

Comment: you can press the search, and type the name of the application there.

Comment: Yes, but it's dirty search for running only applications.

Comment: I found the filters in search widget. It works. Thank you, everybody.

Answer (score 1):

[Gesture Search](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.gesturesearch) will do something similar. It finds apps, contacts, bookmarks and music tracks.

Comment: +1 this is nice, I wish there would be a app indexing all these items, but let you search via keyboard instead of gestures?

Answer (score 0):

The home launcher *Go Launcher Ex* gives you a search field for this, type in first letters and it will show matching apps. But it only lists apps, no music tracks or bookmarks.

Answer (score -1):

It really depends what you mean applications in android are usually run using something similar to com.company.theirapp so you would need a "hashmap" for example which relates the application name to the actual apk name.